# Not receiving Amazon SES bounce notification emails

Tags: amazon-ses

I have an Amazon SES account - it's sending emails fine.

However - if I send to invalid email addresses I never get bounce notifications. I also do not get them if sending to bounce@simulator.amazonses.com as a test.

Sender email is just my mail email address.

Howe can I trouble shoot this?

Comment: I am facing same problem. I was able to confirm subscription for bounces but unable to receive bounce hits (notifications)

Comment: Look in your spam folder - eventually i found them there